# Qt5.6 QML, why are dynamic models destroyed after garbage collection?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt5.6

I have a variable number of components, so i'm trying to give each one its own `model`. In this example, i just create one, but the idea is the same.

GC() is a bit random, so in the example, i *force* the gc() after a click to flush out the problem. What happens is that the `model` is destroyed and becomes null. after that the click method cannot use it.

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

import com.example.qml 1.0

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    // builder of dynamic models
    ModelFactory { id: maker }

    Column
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater
        {
            // create dynamic model
            model: maker.makeModel();
            delegate: Label
            {
                id: label
                text: model.name

                MouseArea
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked:
                    {
                        // works once until gc()
                        console.log("clicked on " + model.name)

                        // wont work anymore. model is destroyed
                        gc();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

c++/mymodel.h:

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

class BoxModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    ~BoxModel()
    {
        // see that it does get destroyed
        qDebug() << "~BoxModel()";
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return 5;
    }  

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override
    {
        int ix = index.row();
        if (ix < 1) return "Larry";
        if (ix < 2) return "Barry";
        if (ix < 3) return "Gary";
        if (ix < 4) return "Harry";
        return "Sally";
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override
    {
        QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
        roles[Qt::UserRole+1] = "name";
        return roles;
    }

};

class ModelFactory: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Q_INVOKABLE BoxModel* makeModel()
    {
        return new BoxModel();
    }    
};
```

main.cpp just registers the types:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>
#include "mymodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<BoxModel>("com.example.qml", 1, 0, "BoxModel");
    qmlRegisterType<ModelFactory>("com.example.qml", 1, 0, "ModelFactory");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

what you see:

[image: runtime]

Click on any of the names. it will work once and after that they will be undefined because `model` becomes null.

eg

```
qml: clicked on Sally
~BoxModel()
qml: clicked on undefined
```

My question is *why* is this, when i still have a reference to it?

In the example, `onClicked` could be changed to `label.text` rather than `model.name` to fix, but the *real* problem is that, in general, the `model` is accessed by the object at any time, for any data. For example, when the box needs to redraw. randomly the data is gone, depending on GC.

I've tried making c++ manage the life of the dynamic model. this could work if i know *when* exactly QML has finished with it.

thanks for info and ideas.

running on windows 8.1/qt5.6mingw

EDIT1: files as a gist,
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86118b67ec804e6149423c14792f312d

Comment: This looks like a genuine bug, thank you for providing a good, clean test case. Do you still have the problem if you remove the factory, and create the instance directly in QML: `model: new BoxModel()`?

Comment: interesting. if i change `model: maker.makeModel()` to `model: BoxModel {}` it works. i'm going to see if this fixes my problem when i have multiple such boxes. thanks.

Comment: Yes this way can work, providing some changes can be made to the underlying code mode. it requires the `BoxModel` to be able to exist on its own without any factory to "know" about it. The problem i had is that i needed to track these internally. had to be done with a singleton, but it can work this way. however, it would be good for the dynamic version to work too. thanks.

Comment: What's stopping you from adding the instance to a global list in a constructor, and removing it in the destructor? You don't need a factory for that.

Answer (score 0):

As Kuba said, this does indeed seem like a bug. However, you can take another approach and take ownership of the models yourself via [`QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#setObjectOwnership). Specifically, changing

```
Q_INVOKABLE BoxModel* makeModel()
{
    return new BoxModel();
}
```

to

```
Q_INVOKABLE BoxModel* makeModel()
{
    BoxModel *model = new BoxModel(this);
    QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(model, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
    return model;
}
```

will fix this (remember to parent the returned model to `BoxModel` so it gets deleted appropriately). The reason for the behaviour is explained [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#ObjectOwnership-enum):

> Generally an application doesn't need to set an object's ownership explicitly. QML uses a heuristic to set the default ownership. By default, an object that is created by QML has JavaScriptOwnership. The exception to this are the root objects created by calling QQmlComponent::create() or QQmlComponent::beginCreate(), which have CppOwnership by default. The ownership of these root-level objects is considered to have been transferred to the C++ caller.
>
> **Objects not-created by QML have CppOwnership by default. The exception to this are objects returned from C++ method calls; their ownership will be set to JavaScriptOwnership.** This applies only to explicit invocations of Q_INVOKABLE methods or slots, but not to property getter invocations.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. The meaning of `JavaScriptOwnership` is precisely what the asker expected: that the JS engine will manage the lifetime and **only destroy the object when there are no more references to it**. In asker's case, it's a clear bug since `model` **is a live reference** yet the referenced object gets destroyed. That should never be the case!

Comment: @Mitch, thanks for your answer. I did try `CppOwnership` originally. but don't know when to delete them. i have not found a QML notifier that tells me QML is done, for example when it destroys the enclosing view.

Comment: @KubaOber that's a good point; it probably is a bug. Still, this is probably the most sane workaround. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @jkjyuio if you parent the models that you create to `BoxModel`, they will get deleted when that does. That seems like a pretty reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with a `ComboBox`.

As a workaround, you may create your own property to keep a strong reference to it:

```
Repeater {
    property QtObject myModel: maker.makeModel();
    model: myModel
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've just faced similar issue, and found your question in process of writing mine. See [QObject gets destroyed after being put into QML variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254141/qobject-gets-destroyed-after-being-put-into-qml-variable/42254142#42254142) for full story, and I'll cite it here.

> What I've figured out that if I set the parent of that QObject before I pass it into QML, then it doesn't get deleted. So, I've concluded that passing unparented QObject into QML scope makes that scope become a parent of QObject and call its destructor after scope ends.