# QObject gets destroyed after being put into QML variable

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Today I've faced strange bug in our program. The object of a class inherited from `QObject` was being deleted by event with type `QEvent::DefferedDelete`, while nobody could possibly send it.

It was passed into QML as QVariant:

```
// cpp: 
        Q_INVOKABLE QVariant currentDevice_v() const {
            return QVariant::fromValue(_current);
        }
// qml: 
       Component.onCompleted: {
            curDevice = devicesModel.currentDevice_v()
            #...
       }
```

Without that qml line everything worked well - nothing produces delete event.

Answer (score 3):

What I've figured out that if I set the parent of that `QObject` before I pass it into QML, then it doesn't get deleted. So, I've concluded that passing unparented QObject into QML scope makes that scope become a parent of `QObject` and call its destructor after scope ends.

Sharing this out, as I haven't found an answer anywhere. But while writing this post I've found similar unanswered issue: [Qt5.6 QML, why are dynamic models destroyed after garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325792/qt5-6-qml-why-are-dynamic-models-destroyed-after-garbage-collection)

Comment: You are right, check here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership . "Additionally, the QML engine respects the normal QObject parent ownership semantics of Qt C++ objects, and will never delete a QObject instance which has a parent." And also if you don't set cpp ownership explicitly on a QObject, QML will claim ownership by default.

Comment: You can either pass a parent to keep C++ ownership (actually the parent is the owner then), or tell the QML engine that you expect the object to be owned by C++, using `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnersship(object, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership)`